# using IJNME Latex class file

Tags: fonts, packages, document-classes

I am trying to prepare a manuscript in Latex using IJNME class file. I have trouble compiling it. I cannot run their example tex file that is in their site under author's guideline. When I am trying to run their file it is looking for `mathtime.sty` file. Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 4):

The `mathtime` package is a very old package used for loading the first versions of what are now the MathTimePro fonts.

As such, this file is not included in any TeX distribution as it requires having the fonts, which are proprietary (and not available any more).

If you install the light version of the MathTimePro fonts, available at [this link](http://www2.pctex.com/downloads.php?product=MTP2L) from [PCTeX](http://pctex.com), you can substitute the call of that package by

```
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
```

However the installation is not easy. You can just remove the call to `mathtime` and change it into

```
\usepackage{mathptmx}
```

that provides a cheap substitute.